# How to inject specific beans in cucumber tests in SpringBoot projects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I have a very simple project structure this way

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── {gradle stuff}
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── my_app
    │   │       ├── ByeByer.java
    │   │       ├── Greeter.java
    │   │       ├── Helloer.java
    │   │       ├── MyApp.java
    │   │       └── MyConfig.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.properties
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── my_app
        │       └── e2e
        │           ├── E2EConfig.java
        │           ├── E2ESteps.java
        │           └── MyE2ETest.java
        └── resources
            └── features
                └── myFeature.feature
```

The code for the classes is the following.

Interface `Greeter`:

```
public interface Greeter {
    public String greet();
}
```

It's basically a dummy interface for a greetings generator.

We have two implementation of this interface, a `ByeByer`, which returns "Bye bye" and `Helloer`, which returns "Hello".

The `main` is in `MyApp`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the configuration is the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    Greeter byebyer(){ 
        return new ByeByer();
    }
}
```

defining that in production, the `Greeter` implementation we want to use is the one generating the "Bye bye" message.

The test part is basically a scenario like this:

```
Feature: Just a feature

  Scenario: Just a scenario

    Given just a given
    When just a when
    Then just a then
```

And the step definition class for it is:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {MyApp.class})
public class E2ESteps implements En{

    @Autowired
    Greeter greeter;

    public E2ESteps() {
        Given("^just a given$", () -> {  });

        When("^just a when$", () -> {  });

        Then("^just a then$", () -> {
           assertEquals("Hello", greeter.greet());
        });
    }
}
```

I'm passing `MyApp.class` because I want to use the same configuration as in production, but I want to override only the `Greeter` implementation, so that it returns "Hello" during the test.

The test runner is simply:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = { "my_app.e2e"},
        features = "classpath:features"
)
public class MyE2ETest {
}
```

How do I amend my project so that I use the same dependency tree as the production one, but overriding only certain beans (in this case the production Greeter implementation)?

Comment: You can use a TestConfiguration overriding the beans you want to override for the test and run tests with that configuration.

Comment: @Marit, how do I plug a TestConfiguration class in my code? I managed to that only using the Import annotation in a nested Configuration class inside the E2ESteps class.

Comment: Create a TestConfiguration class and on your StepDefinitions, specify you can to run it with that class (in Kotlin: `@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestConfiguration::class])`). The TestConfiguration can still use component scan.